# How to use player's input for a certain circumstance throughout the game

Tags: python-3.x

So I'm working on a text-based game in PyCharm and my player has the option to choose a gender. However, how can I use the gender that has been chosen by the player for the entirety of the game. I don't want to re-write the game again for each gender.

The story of the game isn't changing whether or not the player chooses male or female, I need the pronoun to change accordingly. So if my player chooses to be a male, the game will refer to the player as a he and if the player is a girl the game will call the player she.

`gender = input("Are You Male or Female?")` This is how the player chooses the gender, I need to input the chosen gender into 3 separate functions and refer to the player in the correct pronoun.

```
# Poor Game
def poor():
    print("\n")
    print("\n")
    print("#")


# Modest Game
def modest():
    print("\n")
    print("\n")
    print("#")


# Noble Game
def noble():
    print("\n")
    print("\n")
    print("#")
```

The gender needs to be specified into these 3 functions.

I've tried making this feature only through `if/else` statements but it seems so incredibly inefficient and wrong. Is there a better way to do it or should I reconsider doing this project in a different language altogether?

My end goal is to have the game be able to refer to the player according to the pronoun they choose.

Comment: Do you want an unique experience for both the genders or do you just want to refer to them with the gender.

Comment: I just need to refer to them with their chosen gender

Comment: what does the sample code has to do with the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a `dict` that holds the mapping between gender and pronoun:

```py
pronouns = {"male": "he",
            "female": "she"}
```

And then in your code:

```py
gender = input("What is your gender? ")

print("{} is sleeping".format(pronouns[gender.lower()]))
```

---

Or alternatively, assuming this don't change throughout the game, just save the pronoun from the start and use that:

```py
gender = input("What is your gender? ")

pronoun = pronouns[gender.lower()]

print("{} is sleeping".format(pronoun))
```

Comment: Thanks so much, this really helped me out!

Answer (score 0):

Make a special variable, something like, player and when you ask for the gender assign the variable with the chosen gender. Then use it in your code in combination with text. See my example:

```py
player = input('What is your gender?') + ' Player'
print('Welcome, ' + player)
```